# How to automate a dynamically changing web page url and autofill using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

How to automate a dynamically changing web page url and autofill using Excel VBA?

Comment: What is the actual problem that you have? It looks like you are initiating a utility bill payment using screen-scraping to fill in elements of an HTML form. Unless the form has been specifically designed for this purpose and the validation is very strong I wouldn't recommend it. You only need one unfortunate glitch and you could find you have paid away all your life savings.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a light on the details, but from what I understand your code is working, but you are wanting to grab a new tab that opens up after your code completes.

You can do this with a function I have and use somewhat regularly. This will look at the URLs in your open browser (whether the browser is hidden or not) and allow you to set your object declaration to the tab containing your url.

> **Warning**: Just as [JohnRC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1992793/johnrc) stated in his comment, automatic manipulation of web pages handling financial transactions is ill-advised. An error in your coding can produce unexpected results. I do not personally recommend automation of financial transactions and any advice you take out of this you do so at your own risk.

### Function:

```
Function GetIE(sLocation As String) As Object

    Dim objShell As Object, objShellWindows As Object, o As Object
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim RetVal As Object

    Set RetVal = Nothing
    Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each o In objShellWindows
        sURL = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        'check the URL and if it's the one you want then
        'assign it to the return value and exit the loop
        sURL = o.document.Location
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sURL Like sLocation Then
            Set RetVal = o
            Exit For
        End If
    Next o

    Set GetIE = RetVal

End Function
```

In your below code, you are now setting `ie2` as the new webpage, with the URL string `"*bildesk.com/id*"`. Once you accomplish this, you can manipulate `ie2` just as you did with your first `IE` object.

```
Sub SearchBot()

    'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
    Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
    Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link

    'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    Dim iedoc As Object

    'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
   IE.navigate "https://www.nbpdcl.co.in/(S(qq5avnlkl4xr2iqstldu0ehl))/frmQuickBillPaymentAll.aspx"

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    'in the search box put cell "A2" value
    IE.document.getElementById("MainContent_txtCANO").Value = _
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

    'click the 'go' button
    IE.document.getElementById("MainContent_btnSubmit").Click

  'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'in the amount box put cell "B2" value
    IE.document.getElementById("MainContent_txtAmountPayable").Value = _
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value

      'in the EMAIL box put cell "C2" value
    IE.document.getElementById("txtEmailId").Value = _
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value

      'in the PHONE box put cell "D2" value
    IE.document.getElementById("txtMobileNo").Value = _
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value

       'click the 'verify' button
    IE.document.getElementById("MainContent_rbtnlstPaymode_0").Checked = True


      'click the 'verify' button
    IE.document.getElementById("MainContent_btnConfirmPay").Click

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'click the 'verify' button
    IE.document.getElementById("MainContent_btnPayNow").Click

    '<--------- Use the function here ---------->

    Dim ie2 As InternetExplorer
    Set ie2 = GetIE("*bildesk.com/id*")


End Sub
```

So just include the function provided with your module and you should be set.